# Событие "Resize()" срабатывает на телефоне даже если просто прокручивать страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. На сайте есть галерея, которая берет нужное количество картинок в зависимости от размера экрана. Была проблема, что при изменении размера экрана (перевернуть телефон) галерея оставалась прежней, поэтому я добавил событие *resize*, но если запускать сайт именно с телефона, то оно срабатывает даже если ты просто листаешь страницу (в отладке от googlegchrome в телефонном режиме не срабатывает). Что можно сделать в этой ситуации, или может есть другое событие?

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    pushImages(lastArray);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Встречал данный вопрос где-то на просторах английского **Stack overflow**. Чем обусловлен данный баг было непонятно, но в качестве решения предлагалось хранить ширину окна. И когда срабатывает resize, проверять, действительно ли ширина изменилась.

```
// Сохраняем где-то ширину
var saved_width = $(window).width();

// В нужном месте ставим проверку
if ($(window).width() != saved_width) {
    saved_width = $(window).width();
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

**UPD** нашёл тему: **[вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257541/android-browser-triggers-jquery-window-resize-on-scrolling)**

---

**UPD2** Как мне подсказывает @Regent в комментариях, баг был связан со строкой ввода адреса, которая то скрывается, то появляется.

---

**UPD3** @Regent Нужно не забывать обновлять значение saved_width

Comment: Почему "было непонятно"? Во втором и третьем ответах к указанному вопросу говорится о том, что связано это со строкой ввода адреса, которая то скрывается, то появляется.

Comment: И, кстати, нужно не забывать обновлять значение `saved_width`.

Comment: @socode, отлично спасибо) ну будем пока таким пользоваться, в будущем надеюсь пофиксят)

Answer (score 0):

Проблему с работой `"resize"` на мобильных устройствах можно решить по другому - Исключить установку этого события на Мобильных и Планшетах.

Не припомню ни одного телефона или планшета, на котором можно изменять размеры окна, соответственно нет никакого смысла устанавливать событие `"resize"`.

Для определения типа устройства используем navigator.userAgent и регулярное выражение.

Это работает:

```
if (!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
{ 
    alert("ПК/Мак");
    // функция срабатывающая при изменении размера окна браузера
    window.addEventListener("resize", razmerOkna);  
}
else 
{
    alert("Мобильный/Планшет");
}
```

Comment: Самый просто способ сделать resize на телефоне - повернуть его из портретной ориентации в альбомную. Ещё почти наверняка плавающие окна и режим разделения экрана. И не уверен про исчезновение адресной строки - вроде бы оно не вызывает resize (хотя, судя по соседнему ответу как раз-таки вызывает), но я не проверял. Ну и вообще, userAgent устарел.

Comment: Адресная строка на Мобильных и Планшетах появляется и исчезает при скролле страницы вверх или вниз.
Появление и скрытие адресной строки вызывает событие `"resize"`.
Для отслеживания поворота из портретной ориентации в альбомную и обратно используется событие `"orientationchange"`.